# Unable to load ejabberd home page ubuntu 16.04

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I am trying to install `ejabberd` in my Ubuntu 16.04.

I have installed `ejabberd` with APT:

```
sudo apt-get install ejabberd
```

Then I registered the admin user:

```
ejabberdctl register admin localhost password
```

Then I also changed the `ejabberd.yml` file. In that file I have changed

```
admin:
  user:
     - "": "localhost"
```

to

```
admin:
  user:
     - "admin": "localhost"
```

Then I restarted `ejabberd`:

```
service ejabberd restart
```

After that I tried to access `ejabberd` via browser with

```
http://localhost:5222/admin
```

But I got the following error

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it.  
The document tree is shown below:

<stream:stream xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" id="11078245051945755090" from="localhost" version="1.0">
  <stream:error>
    <xml-not-well-formed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams"/>
  </stream:error>
</stream:stream>
```

If I change the port to 5280, then it doesn't load anything.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to go to https://localhost:5280/admin

jabbed uses https by default and there is no redirect setup to redirect the http connection to https

Comment: I dont have SSL enabled, so you mean I have to buy it before using it?

Answer (score 0):

http://localhost:5280/admin/ should work

I installed ejabberd on Ubuntu 16 and changed the config file (ejabberd.yml) to add admin@localhost to acl

acl:
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin@localhost"

Restarted ejabberd server and then registered admin user

Opened http://localhost:5280/admin/ and was able to log in using admin@localhost

Comment: Thanks, but now I have shifted to MQTT which is quite simple and faster